# How to use datepicker Dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have this input boxes, now how can i use datepicker dynamically

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date[0]">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date[1]">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date[2]">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date[3]">
```

i tried to code it something like this but this wont work only the first input changes

```
$('name^="date"').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
})
```

i want to code it dynamically not like this

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({})
$('#datepicker2').datepicker({})....
```

is it possible? thanks for any reply.

Comment: Your selector is wrong. it should be something like this $('[name^="date"]')

Comment: Also note that `ID` should be unique. You currently have four `input` elements with the same ID.

Comment: @fizzix i fixed it i remove the id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this case you should use a class instead of a ID:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date[0]">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date[1]">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date[2]">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date[3]">
```

Then you can simply call the datepicker for every element with this class:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('[name^="date"]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me even if duplicate ids are exist. How ever remove duplicate ids always.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>      
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[name^="date"]').datepicker();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date[0]" />
    <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date[1]" />
    <input type="text" id="datepicker3" name="date[2]" />
    <input type="text" id="datepicker4" name="date[3]" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="your_input" name="your_input" />
<input type="text" class="your_input" name="your_input2" />
```

JS:

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".your_input" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Optional Fast load datapicker:

```
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $('body').on('focus',".your_input", function(){
              $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
        });
      });
      </script>
```